# irrationalPath Error in Dojo 1.8

Tags: dojo

I have the following HTML code from within a Grails GSP page that is giving me an "Uncaught Error: irrationalPath" error from the Javascript console.

I have Dojo under in the following hierarchy:
web-app
   /js
      /lib
         /dojo
            /dojo
            /dijit
            /dojox

I have not found any documentation as to what is causing this. The createLink tags resolve to the following url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tfs-web2/static/js/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

and

```
baseUrl: "/tfs-web2/js/lib/"
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<g:createLinkTo file="/js/lib/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>">

    <script>dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async: true,
        baseUrl: "${resource(uri:'/')}/js/lib/",
        packages: [
            { name: "dojo", location: "dojo/dojo" },
            { name: "dijit", location: "dojo/dijit" }
        ]
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<g:createLinkTo file="/js/lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"/>"></script>

    <script>
        require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/fx"], function(ready, fx){
            ready(function(){
                require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/_base/window"], function(Button, win){
                    ready(function(){
                        new Button({}).placeAt(win.body());
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
</body>
</html>
```

edit: I can get this to work if I use a CDN instead of referencing my local packages. I don't want to use a CDN though so I'm still interested in knowing how I can get this to work using a local copy of Dojo.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="isDebug:true, async:true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to specify `baseUrl`. Dojo will auto detect it.

`packages` should be `paths` and you only need to define custom modules. `dojo`, `dijit` and `dojox` will be mapped automatically.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/config.html

Comment: I removed the baseUrl setting and also tried to remove the entire dojoConfig as well. I still get the same error.

Comment: In the console debugger of your browser, there should be an object logged that will give more information.  Otherwise you can use the uncompressed version of dojo (dojo.js.uncompressed.js) and put a breakpoint on `throw makeError("irrationalPath", mid);` (~line934) and see what causes the error to be thrown.

Comment: I got this to work by using Dojo 1.9 instead. I noticed that in the section that throws that Exception, there were some additional code compared to 1.8.x. Unfortunately since I have something that's already working, I haven't dug in to find out exactly what is causing it 1.8 to fail for me.